# How to make a diagonal Carousel in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

How to make a diagonal Carousel in SwiftUI?

I am also trying to make the middle element pop out more than the other ones (circle to left and right).

Please see the below image to see what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

*What I have tried:*

I have tried using a Scroll View, however this can only be vertical or horizontal.

Comment: maybe add a rotation effect to the horizontal ScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a rotation effect to the view that holds the circles, which can simply be an `HStack`:

```
HStack(spacing: 40) {
    ForEach(0..<3) { _ in
        Color.blue
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    }
}.rotationEffect(.degrees(-40))
```

That'll result in this:

[image: result]

If you wanted to scroll diagonally, you could also replace that `HStack` in the example above with a `ScrollView` and make the scroll view horizontal.

---

You could also work with alignment guides, depending on what you're trying to achieve.